# PyDev fails to install on Eclipse for Mac

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I am attempting to install PyDev in Eclipse for Mac (OSX version 10.8.3). After installing PyDev I go to preferences to configure it for use, and it does not appear on the list. If I go back to help > install new software and click "What is already installed?" PyDev does not appear on the list. I have attempted reinstalling PyDev (many times), restarting Eclipse, restarting my Mac, and have searched for any problems similar to mine, but have come up with nothing. I have Python 3.3 installed, and also Python 2.6 (installed 2.6 when a guide told me 2.6 is the build used by the project).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Have a nice day!

Greg Anthony

Comment: I think the problem is that you're not using a java 7 vm which is a new pre-requisite for running pydev 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

I think I just solved the problem.

I tried to install PyDev, got a long way through to a dialog with a progress bar that seemed to be about the last step.

A dialog box asking me to approve a certificate popped up behind the progress-bar dialog, when it was about half-way along. I clicked OK and both dialogs *immediately* disappeared.

PyDev was not installed.

I did it again, but this time looked at the certificate dialog. You have to tick the certificate, and then click OK. Installation continued.

Now I have PyDev.

YMMV, good luck.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to share how you got around this. Even though a solution may be trivial (as this was), that doesn't mean other people aren't having similar brain-farts (as I did).